# SoundCloud's embed bloated garbage

Tags: soundcloud

### This is a complaint about the quality of the content served by soundcloud's embed API (iframe)

The main css file has 235 KB (160kb gzipped) where 92% is not used at all.

The main JS file has 450 KB  (149kb gzipped), possibly following the above situation.

We developers spend much time optimizing bytes from our websites. Seeing this after hours of work makes us think that soundcloud just don't care about us and users.

Comment: Hey -- sorry you feel that way; I can promise it's not the reality. In terms of the CSS, yep, it's a lot there, including a custom font and some inlined base-64 images. The reason there's some unused CSS is because we have our own sort-of bootstrap (check the mini styleguide here http://soundcloud.github.io/sc.css/), and right now it's not so easy to modularize it. It's definitely something we want to improve though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The main css file has 235 KB (160kb gzipped) where 92% is not used at all.

I am not sure you counted all possible views that widget might have.

> The main JS file has 450 KB (149kb gzipped), possibly following the above situation

While we are trying hard to keep the weight of the widget low, you should realize that HTML5 widget is a complicated single-page JavaScript application that has many features, including API hooks to control the widget, ability to resolve various URLs, a way to customise the widget, a way for widgets to communicate with each other and more

> We developers spend much time optimizing bytes from our websites. Seeing this after hours of work makes us think that soundcloud just don't care about us and users.

If you feel very strong about this, I would suggest to build only the functionality you need from the widget on your own – SoundCloud provides public API, so building a player with similar UI that only does things you need is your best bet – you could use tools like http://zohararad.github.io/audio5js/ or even https://github.com/kilokeith/soundcloud-soundmanager-player etc. for playback.

Good luck!

Comment: I appreciate your feedback very much.

Comment: When you say "I am not sure you counted all possible views that widget might have." does not mean that you could optimize the css file to deliver only what the widget is going to make use? At least, approximate it..
Abou the JS file I understand that the whole thing happens inside it, I can't say it is too big.
I'm going to check the API to see if I can find a way to embed a player with less kbs.
I'm a admirer of your company and what you provide for the internet, it is the kind of thing that after you discover, you can't live without. Keep up the work, ty.

Comment: s/abou/about; s/admirer/admire

Comment: Hey, thanks for the kind words, what I wanted to say is that when you run an analyser for the selectors usage, you usually only apply it to the currently built DOM or even HTML, – while we mostly build it up from JavaScript templates which aren't scanned by the analysis tool.

We are definitely aware of the weight and we are trying to keep it low though. 

Thanks for your feedback!

Comment: Also: by shipping a single package for all 'types' of widget, it means that we're making full use of caching and you're not downloading that package multiple times if you're on a page with multiple widgets. Further, API which the widget provides means that we can't necessarily know what it will need to display.